# how to find 000005000 and 5000 equal in string c#

Tags: c#, string

I tried using String.Contains() but not getting the expected result.

00005000 is not equal to 500 but equal to 5000. But not to convert this string to integer.

It is one of the conditions inside lambda expression. I cant share the code so asking this way. I can't check condition by casting into int since it will throw error as
"`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ParseInt(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`"

Any help much appreciated please.

Comment: make integer comparision. `int.Parse`

Comment: condition is we should not convert it into integer.

Comment: when you use int.parse, it will not convert the original value, so you should be Ok.
`var isequal = int.Parse(str) == 5000 ? true : false;`

Comment: Its working. but comparing value is variable. IF i pass 500, its passing. 500 not equal to 5000 right

Comment: if you can't convert it to an integer (i.e. homework), you could simply remove leading zero's using `myString.TrimStart('0')` before comparing

Comment: You could always use `string.EndsWith()` instead. That should give you the correct results for your example values.

Comment: Solve a simpler problem. Implement the following method: "method M takes a string and returns a string. If the string begins with 0 and has two or more characters, then the string returned is the string without the leading zero. Otherwise, the string is returned unchanged."  Once you have implemented method M, can you see how to use it to solve your actual problem?  Remember, computer programming is about solving *small* problems and combining those solutions to solve larger problems. So solve the small problem first!

Comment: @itsme86: Whether it work for these inputs is not relevant. The relevant question is whether your proposal works for *all* inputs. So: does it? (Hint: no. Find a case where it fails.)

Comment: @curiousDev: Do you have to support 005000 and 00005000 (i.e. both strings zero padded)? Or only 00005000 and 5000 (i.e. one zero padded string versus an actual number)? If the latter, then itsme86's solution seems like it could work.

Comment: itsme86 : It worked. Dont know how to vote your answer as right. thank you

Comment: @curiousDev: itsme86's solution is wrong. **Start thinking like a professional programmer if you want to be one**.  Find a case where that solution is wrong, don't look for cases that confirm that it is right, because it isn't. Finding a case that falsifies this solution is not hard.

Comment: @curiousDev I'll post what Eric Lippert implies, `"0001500".EndsWith("500")` returns true. So itsme86's solution is wrong

Comment: @curiousDev why not convert to int just for testing ?

Comment: @curiousDev - check my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's get a really simple case out of the way: if both "numbers" have no leading 0s, then just comparing them as strings should be good enough for equality. So the problem we run into is what do we do with leading zeros? There are a few paths to take, but the most straightforward is to just get rid of them. So we'll write a method to do that:

```
public static string RemoveLeadingZeros(this string input) { ... }
```

There's no implementation because that's the meat of the problem, and this seems like homework. But let's assume we can write that method.

Once we have that it, the comparison method becomes trivial:

```
public static bool AreEqual(string firstNumber, string secondNumber)
{
    // Code assumes firstNumber and secondNumber are actually numeric values in string form; you can add code to verify that if that assumption isn't right
    return RemoveLeadingZeros(firstNumber) == RemoveLeadingZeros(secondNumber);
}
```

This won't work when you have different representations of the "same" number (e.g. "1e6" and "1000000") but it'll solve the basic problem.

So now you have a new problem to solve: how can you remove the leading 0s from a number? Well, as Eric Lippert asks above: how can you remove *one* leading zero? Can you apply that technique to remove them all?

The takeaway from all this is that you shouldn't guess at the problem, and you shouldn't always be looking for short-cuts immediately. If you can't even think of a straightforward solution, try thinking of ways to simplify the problem into one that you *can* solve, and then figure out how to reduce the more complex problem into the simpler version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public bool AreStrinEqualAsNumber(string num1, string num2)
{
    if (n1 == null ||n2 == null)
        return false;

    // remove padded zero's from both the number.
    var n1 = num1.TrimStart('0');
    var n2 = num2.TrimStart('0');

    // if after removing zero's the length are not equal the numbers cant be equal.
    if (n1.Length != n2.Length)
        return false;

    // do a character by character comparision
    for(int i = 0; i < n1.Length; i++)
    {
        // number cant be equal if characters differ.
        if (n1[i] != n2[i])
            return false;
    }

    // no different character was found.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a conversion to integer:

```
var strNum = "00005000";
var intNum = Convert.ToInt64(strNum);
```

Comment: Read comments `condition is we should not convert it into integer. `